# react-native-keyboard-spacer how to use onToggle

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I'm using react-native-keyboard-spacer.
I want to implement the feature of automatically popping up the keyboard.
The documentation says `onToggle method is called when when keyboard toggles. Two parameters passed through, keyboardState (boolean, true if keyboard shown) and keyboardSpace (height occupied by keyboard)`
Can anyone show me an example of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onToggle() is only called *after* the keyboard is toggled. To achieve the functionality you desire, just use the built in method in TextInput to focus an input when a component finishes mounting:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._myTextInput.focus();
}

render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        ref={component => this._myTextInput = component}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onToggle` get's called when the keyboard is either shown or hidden. If you want to pop up the keyboard without the user clicking anything, then you would need to `focus()` on a textInput.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleOnToggle(keyboardState, keyboardSpace) {
    // Do whatever you want with keyboardState
}

render() {
    return <View>
        <KeyboardSpacer onToggle={this.handleOnToggle} />
    </View>
}
```

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.